# magento cart empty in internet explorer after updating

Tags: magento, internet-explorer, cart

In internet-Explorer after updating quantity of product on checkout page,
page is redirect to empty cart page.
I tried the cookie solution but it doesn't work for my site

Comment: please add more details for users to provide information.

Comment: did you fix it ? :) I'm facing the same situation

Answer (score 0):

Here's your Solution:

```
Set cookie domain: http://www.domain.com/
```

Set your cookie domain to: `.domain.com`

This is due to the cookie problem, not in browser but in Magento itself. In Magento, by default cookie’s lifetime is set to 3600 (1 hour). But if the end users computer time runs ahead of server’s time, cookies will not get set for magento frontend as well as backend. For example, end user’s computer time is 1 hour forward than server’s time, that means the cookie (holding user’s session id) will expire as soon as user logs in or tries to add an item.

To solve this, set cookie’s lifetime to 86400 (1 day) instead of 1 hour and everything will work as expected. You can also set cookie lifetime to 0, so that cookie will only expire when the user’s browser is closed.

Go to: Magento backend -> Sytem -> Configuration -> Web -> Session and Cookie Management Set cookie lifetime to 86400 and save. Everything will work as expected now.

Comment: Hi,I tried both solutions but still I facing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In case you or someone else out there is experiencing the same problem (I too was stuck on this issue for a long time).

I tried editing the files, I tried cookie lifetime extension, I tried the URL change, nothing worked.

What finally made my Magento 1.9 work and resolve empty cart is when I went to Config > Web > Under the cookie session management section, **make sure the *cookie domain* and *cookie path* is blank**. Once you have done that, save, clear cache, and everything should work properly.

Let me know if it works for you! :)

Comment: No, this doesn't work. 
When I return from shopping cart to the homepage, my header cart display wrong cart amount.